# HelpLibManager.exe: How to avoid "a file required by help library manager is missing" error box?

Tags: locale, inno-setup, messagebox, help-viewer, help-viewer-1.0

We have an installation of our .NET Framework developer tool designated for .NET 4+ and VS 2010-2013. The installator includes the accompanying help file in the MS Help Viewer format that should be installed automatically.

Our installation is built with Inno Setup, and here is the corresponding part of the setup script used to install the electronic documentation:

```
[Run]
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale en-US /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale zh-TW /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale zh-CN /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale fr-FR /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale de-DE /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale it-IT /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale ja-JP /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale ko-KR /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale ru-RU /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale es-ES /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale ar-SA /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale cs-CZ /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale pl-PL /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale pt-BR /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0,AppRoot|{pf}\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\}HelpLibManager.exe; Parameters: "/product VS /version 100 /locale tr-TR /install /sourceMedia ""{app}\Docs\MSHelp3\HelpContentSetup.msha"""; Flags: skipifdoesntexist
```

As you can see, we try to install the documentation for every possible locale of VS. However, if a particular locale does not exist, the following error box is displayed:

[image: HelpLibManager.exe "a file required by help library manager is missing" error box]

One of the recipes of how to avoid this message is described on [this page](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/languagepacksformicrosofthelpviewer10) (see the "Missing File Error: Accessing foreign language catalogs" section.) However, this is a manual solution we can't use in the automatic product installation.

How to avoid this issue if we need to install a Help Viewer documentation from an installation package?